# Reversing second half of a linked list

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I have a linked list defined as follows:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null
```

The goal is to reverse second half as a separate linked list;

**Expected output**: 5 -> 4 -> null

Here are the two methods I wrote in my linked list class for this purpose;

```
 class SLL:   

    def reverse(self):
        prev = None
        curr = self.head
        while curr is not None:
            temp = curr.get_next()
            curr.set_next(prev)
            prev = curr
            curr = temp
    
        self.head = prev
        return self.head




    def second_half(self):
        fast = self.head
        slow = self.head
   # fast pointer moves twice as fast as compared to slow pointer

        while fast is not None and fast.get_next() is not None:
            fast = fast.get_next().get_next()
            slow = slow.get_next()
        
        temp = slow.get_next()
        slow.set_next(None)
        temp = self.reverse(temp)
        return temp
```

But when we invoke the `reverse` method above, with argument as `temp`, we're getting following error message;

```
TypeError: reverse() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can I please get some help how to rectify this error and obtain desired output? thanks

Comment: i guess your reverse method is missing temp argument `reverse(self, temp)`. TypeError clearly states you're passing two arguments one is class and the other is temp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The goal is to reverse second half as a separate linked list;

That would mean the result should be an instance of `SLL`. That means you should somewhere create that new linked list with a call of `SLL`.

So I'd suggest to change that function as follows:

```
    def second_half(self):
        fast = self.head
        slow = self.head

        while fast is not None and fast.get_next() is not None:
            fast = fast.get_next().get_next()
            slow = slow.get_next()
        
        temp = slow.get_next()
        slow.set_next(None)
        
        # changed code below:
        newlist = SSL()
        newlist.head = temp; 
        newlist.reverse()
        return newlist
```